# Not able to send files data from front-end (react.js) to back-end (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an application that stores to its state files' content, whether images, audio or both, as shown here with the `mediaAudio` object key:

[image]

In my `react.js` code, I make my post as such:

```
   var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('data', formData);

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/post-entry',
      data: bodyFormData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

In my `node.js` code, I retrieve my data as such:

```
app.post('/post-entry', (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body.data;
  console.log(data);
});
```

However, I'm not able to get the data being logged, it returns `undefined`.

What is happening?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot directly get data from content-type `multipart/form-data`. You have to use parsers like multer

Comment: In my node.js you mean? So my react.js is okay?

Comment: As long as `bodyFormData` has some value, the value should go to nodejs and the problem wont be on react side. Adding multer middleware to nodejs route might solve this issue